# Unity3D - Smooth rotation for seek steering behavior

Tags: unity, rotation, ai, steering-behaviors

I am trying to implement Reynolds' seek steering behaviour, but I am having problems on the rotation part. This is what I have:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
// get position of current waypoint
        Vector3 targetPos = new Vector3(path[currentWaypoint].x, transform.position.y, path[currentWaypoint].z);

        // velocity vector towards target
        Vector3 desiredVelocity = targetPos - transform.position;

        // calculate the steerforce required for the desired velocity based on current velocity
        Vector3 steerForce = desiredVelocity - currentVelocity;
        steerForce = new Vector3(steerForce.x, 0, steerForce.z);
        steerForce = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(steerForce, maxSteer);

        // create a move vector to be added to agent's current position
        // Then normalize it so it can be scaled according to the agent's max speed
        Vector3 moveVector = steerForce.normalized * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        transform.Translate(moveVector);
}
```

How would I do it so my agent will be rotated smoothly based only on the code above? I tried rotating based on the current velocity, but the agents is rapidly rotated in one frame towards the target waypoint. I am not working with rigidbodies.

Am I doing something wrong? What am I missing?

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: Have you looked at Vector3.lerp?

Comment: In addition, none of the code here deals with rotation, only movement.

Comment: @Draco18s Yes, that is because I am not sure how to handle rotation using vectors. That is what I am trying to find out how to do.

Comment: @user3797758 Isn't that for position movements?

Comment: it's for getting one vector from state A to B over a certain amount of time. Since I don't see you doing anything with quaternions i don't see why it wouldn't work...

Comment: @user3797758 I was using Quaternion.Slerp but that is not what I wanted. I want the rotation to change based on the new steerForce applied, while still affecting the rotation/movement gradually. Maybe I am not understanding the whole concept correctly, so could you give an example using my code?

Comment: @JackM36 do you want to figure out the current heading rotation based on the motion vector? That's trigonometry.

Comment: @Draco18s Yes. I want to rotate my agent to look towards the direction it is heading (not the target location), just like real humans do. And how would that be calculated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking up how Reynolds seek steering works i realised that lerping wouldn't work. What you have to do is limit the steering to the maximum force which should be set very low to avoid instant steering.

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    //move to position
    transform.Translate(Seek(new Vector3()) * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}

Vector3 Seek(Vector3 target)
{
    //Reynolds steering behaviour = desired - velocity
    //Should be global variables
    float maxSpeed = 4f;    //fastest possible speed
    float maxForce = 0.1f;  //turning speed of the object

    //the direction that you need to go to reach the target
    Vector3 desired = target - transform.position;
    desired.Normalize();
    desired *= maxSpeed;

    //steering (reynolds steering)
    Vector3 steer = desired - currentVelocity;
    steer.y = 0f; //assuming you want 2D motion on the XZ plane

    //limit the steering
    if(steer.sqrMagnitude > maxForce * maxForce)
    {
        steer.Normalize();
        steer *= maxForce;
    }

    return steer;
}
```

This should work but it's untested. Tell me if there is a problem with it. You will **need to change** the target location in the update method as i doubt that you want to go the the origin of the scene.

**EDIT**

To get the rotation to work you need to get the object to face into the direction that it is moving. So by changing the update function too this it should work (in theory):

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    transform.Translate(Seek(new Vector3()) * Time.fixedDeltaTime);//change position
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(currentVelocity);//change the rotation
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The movement works, but the steering does not seem to get limited, it just immediately change towards the next target when one is reached (it is not done gradually). When I lower maxForce, the only thing that is limited is the moving speed

Comment: Oh I completely misunderstood the problem.

Comment: @JackM36 So you want the object to slowly turn towards the target as it's moving?

Comment: Yes, when the target is not straight ahead, I want the agent (object) to steer towards it (based on desired velocity and the steer force), and at the same time rotate towards the direction it is heading, much like a car or a real human

Comment: You just need to get the agent (object) to face the direction that it's moving in

Comment: I will mark it as accepted because I solved my problem, but I need one last thing. why do you use the sqrMagnitude to check if you should limit the steer force?

Comment: because maxForce is also squared, I guess that you could just use magnitude and not square maxForce.... I know that squaring it works so thats what i gave you. You could try without squaring it all just keep in mind that you will probably have to change all your values until it works again

Answer (score 0):

I have a MathHelper class for stuff like this (I've got a fast/inaccurate distance check, various radians-degrees conversions, this angle trig, safe angle addition, a snap method...).  Here's the one that is of interest to you:

```
public static double AngleBetweenPointsRadiansDouble(Vector2 P1, Vector2 P2) {
    return Math.Atan2( ( P2.y - P1.y ), ( P2.x - P1.x ) );
}
```

You'd want to plug in Vector2 versions of your Vector3s's `.x` and `.z` (as you are ignoring the Y component).

```
Vector2 pos = new Vector2(transform.position.x,transform.position.z);
double angle = MathHelper.AngleBetweenPointsRadiansDouble(pos, pos+moveVector);
```

You'd want to convert this to degrees and then apply it to the transform's eulerAngles's Y component.

Comment: Thanks! I did not make it exactly that way, but this helped!

Comment: @JackM36 Glad to help. Feel free to mark my answer as useful/accepted. :)